# Comments in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to adds comments functionality to my django website. There is a tutorial on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/comments/. However, as you can see, it is deprecated for my version of django (1.6) and no longer supported. I still tried following the tutorial and ran into this error when I did "python manage.py syncdb":

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError django_comments: No module named django_comments
```

Any help on how to debug this would be highly appreciated. I know I shouldn't be using the comment framework since it has been deprecated. Therefore, alternatives would also be highly appreciated. The tutorial talks about Disqus but I had some trouble setting it up since Disqus' documentation is not very helpful and Google doesn't seem to yield anything useful either when I search for "Disqus django".

Comment: could you try a pluggable comments app? or install the external comments app referenced in the documenation link?
https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments
http://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module name is still `'django.contrib.comments'` and not `django_comments` in Django 1.6. You need to change the value you added in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: thanks for the help! did that. Now I'm getting a new kind of error. "CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
comments.comment: 'site' has a relation with model <class 'django.contrib.sites.models.Site'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract."

Comment: You also need `django.contrib.sites` to be installed (and `SITE_ID = 1` in settings also)